# White screen when running Cordova 2.6.0 project on Xcode

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

I have this problem. It's intermittent though but I fear future user of my app will experience it too and I don't want that. I upgraded to cordova-2.6.0. I'm now experiencing a problem when running my application on an iPad.

On the Console everything seems to be working. The splashscreen display's properly but after the splashscreen (intermittent) index.html doesn't load or its plain white screen.

So here is what I see on the console :

```
Multi-tasking -> Device: Yes, App: YES
Resetting Plugins due to page load.
Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/(numbers)/Project.app/www/index.html
DEPRECATION NOTICE: The Connection ReachableViaWWAN return value of '2g' is deprecated as of Cordova version 2.6.0 and will be changed to 'cellular' in a future release.
```

Then whitescreen!! ( Just like the white walkers. lol )

Anyways on my Cordova-2.6.0.js I changed the xhr.open

from: `xhr.open('GET', 'cordova_plugins.json', true);`
to  : `xhr.open('GET', 'file:///cordova_plugins.json', true);`

Only because I can't test my app on a browser. Just googled the fix though.

Any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error might not be connected to the deprecation notice. I have been getting that notice in iPhone with no issues.

Check if you have all the required splash screen files for iPad and added those to config.xml:
https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml